# После установки пакета NuGet visual studio перестала видеть все ссылки

Tags: c#, nuget

Устанавливал пакет CefSharp, во время установки VS зависла и закрылась, после перезапуска ни одна ссылка не подключена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавлять заново, все равно не видит, в свойствах к ссылкам поле "путь" пустое.

Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: вам стоит указать больше подробностей, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему (ос, версия VS, установленные пакеты и тд) также может стоить создание issue в [багтрекер CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) или [форум VS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)

Comment: Попробуйте просто почистить проект. Закройте студию, удалите из проекта `bin` и `obj`, далее откройте его и ПКМ по проекту - "очистить", там же "пересобрать". Во многих случаях такое помогает. Также можете попробовать выполнить восстановление пакетов, только вот команду я забыл...